# How to write a google sheets query for summing by columns

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, google-sheets-formula, flatten, google-query-language

I've got a sheet where I'd like to sum each column B-D but filtered/grouped by the value in Column A.

If I use a basic `query` like

```
=QUERY(B1:N100, "select sum(B) where A = 'whatever'")
```

then I get a single value out- the values in B, summed.

How do I alter this query so that I get a single value out for each column, B-N?

Comment: I have discovered `SUMIF` but I'm not sure if there's a way to do it with `QUERY` to get all the layout goodness that comes with it

Comment: please share the sample spreadsheet  with your desired output and remove sensitive information.

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(A1:N100, 
 "select sum(B),sum(C),sum(D),sum(E),sum(F),sum(G),sum(H),sum(I),sum(J),sum(K),sum(L),sum(M),sum(N) 
  where A = 'whatever'")
```

or:

```
=QUERY({A1:N100}, 
 "select "&JOIN(",", "sum(Col"&SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(B:N))&")")&" 
  where Col1 = 'whatever'")
```

or:

```
=BYCOL(FILTER(B1:N100, A1:A100="whatever"), LAMBDA(x, SUM(x)))
```